# PHP image resize using nearest-neighbor interpolation?

Tags: php, resize, image-manipulation

I have a 16x16 sprite in PNG or GIF image format, and would like to display it on a website at 64 x 64 in all its pixelated glory. In Firefox 3.6+ and IE I can do this easily with CSS using [image-rendering and -ms-interpolation-mode](http://articles.tutorboy.com/css/resize-images-in-same-quality.html), but as this doesn't work in all browsers I'd like to resize the image on the fly using PHP instead. What's the best way to resize images using nearest-neighbor interpolation in PHP?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep the pixelation during your resize, you will want to do something like this using the GD library:

```
<?php
// create GD image resource from source image file
$src = imagecreatefromgif('test.gif');

// create new GD image resource with indexed color
$dest = imagecreate(64, 64);

// copy/resize image without resampling
imagecopyresized($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 64, 16, 16);

// output result
header('Content-type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);
?>
```

I have tested the code, and the pixelation remains in tact. You will have to adapt the code to also accept png files as input, which should be fairly easy since each of the GD gif functions also have corresponding png functions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) project, if u need resize GIFs too.

You can use GD, but, it's possible that u lose some EXIF data.

The [KusabaX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kusabax/) Project has a great function to convert image. Check the file "/inc/func/posts.php" at line 58. ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I know it's possible with GD, but I want to know the best way to do it. Losing EXIF data would not matter for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/misc/#interpolate

http://www.francodacosta.com/blog/phmagick/examples/resizing-images

This is a bit of information regarding interpolation in imagemagick. 
The second link is to a class called phMagick which is a full featured wrapper around the imagemagick libraries. The example linked is for basic resize operations but doesn't have the interpolation flags set for the command line call that the library makes.

You *do* have full access to the command line through the class and if there is a lack of interpolation flag support there is an easy mechanism for extending the class via plugins. It is also php5 ready.

If this doesn't point you in the right direction I don't know what will. If nothing else the phMagick classes should give you a good starting point for writing a leaner wrapper for your specific purpose.

Comment: I didn't think I had access to Imagemagick but I just checked with my hosting service, and it turns out I do. So this is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, it doesn't matter. Cache the result. Save down a hard-copy of the result and output that. Do it only once if the image never changes without identifying info changing too.

You might argue that this isn't the correct answer. That it isn't what you asked for. But it is the BEST answer. It will save the most processing time over time. To the point where the initial load time of the image resize in the first place becomes entirely moot, It could take 30 seconds to render, and it will only affect one person, once.

Comment: It does matter - he has a slightly abnormal use case and wanted to know a convenient way to handle nearest neighbor/integer interpolation from a php file. Telling him what to do after he has solved the problem he asked about is sort of rude - especially when you didn't even attempt to answer the actual question.

Comment: "Thanks - I know it's possible with GD, but I want to know the best way to do it." The OP already knows a way to do it. They are looking for the 'best way' and I have given that information. The best way is to not waste time finding a better way, and to cache the result of the way he/she already knows.

Comment: My question is about how to resize images while preserving the pixel-art quality of the images, using PHP's GD functions. So no, this is not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Symphony](http://see.weareinto.com/3qE7) is a great PHP powered framework and it utilizes the [JIT manipulator](http://see.weareinto.com/3qEQ), which makes all of this a piece of cake! :P

An image in your case would be

```
<img src="http://yoursite.com/image/1/64/64/0/images/16pixels.jpg"/>
```